# Does intern add Strings to String Constant pool?

Tags: java, string

As per the Java docs Specification-

> When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then the string from the pool is returned. **Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned.**

Why doesn't the following code create a literal in Constant pool when interned?

`String a = "abc";
 String b = a.substring(1);
 b.intern();`

[image]

Why shouldn't be "bc" added to the String Constant pool.

Comment: Don't confuse literals in the class constants with the String `intern` pool.

Comment: But `b.intern();` fetches the reference of the available String from the Constant pool

Comment: do you expect that `b.intern()` changes the class file?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It has its own pool to which Strings from the class constant pool (which isn't really a pool, it's constant) are added.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis 
So,
`String a = "abc";
 String b = a.substring(1);
 b.intern();
String c = "bc";
System.out.println(b==c)'
results in true?

Comment: Question makes no sense. The literal is clearly present in the constant pool dump and String.intern is completely unrelated.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis
If we write,
`String a = "abc";    

    String b = "abc";`
As the literals are interned, will the reference of b fetched from intern pool or Constant pool?